# Show content before main content based on color attribute

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, permalinks

I found a code snippet to display the content before the main content and it worked.

Currently the content is displayed on all pages. (except shop page)

The code :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'BannerShop', 35 );

function BannerShop(){

if(!is_shop()){
echo '<img src="https://localhost/demosite/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/512x356.png" >';
     }
  }
```

What I want to ask is, how to display content only for color attribute products in the form of links.

Example :

The display (content) will **ONLY SHOW** when the url is like this :

*mysite.com/color/red/*

Sorry if the explanation is not good because I don't really understand this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your question is about displaying that extra content, if the current query is for a product archive page only showing products of a certain attribute 'color'.

Each WooCommerce attribute is an independent taxonomy.

WordPress's `is_tax('parameter')` function checks, if the query is for an existing custom taxonomy archive page (other than category & tag) & if the query is for that specific taxonomy `'parameter'`, in your case `'color'`.

So, this code snippet in your `functions.php` or equivalent plugin should work:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'BannerShop', 35 );

function BannerShop(){
    (is_tax('color')) {
        echo '<img src="https://localhost/demosite/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/512x356.png" >';
    }
}
```

Though, to make the above template WooCommerce override work, declare WooCommerce support for your theme by adding the following lines to your functions.php or plugin equivalent:

```
function theme_add_woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_add_woocommerce_support' );
```

Comment: hi @bitski.. thanks for your reply.  I have tried using your code but it didn't work for me and it makes the site showing error (except the shop page).  Even so, I really appreciate your help, thank you

Comment: What kind of error is shown?

Comment: Hi @bitski Error shown like this http://prnt.sc/1xkmpks

Comment: @carlozsan Hmm, i would need more info about the error message and page giving it. Is it perhaps a live page?

Comment: yes, please...and this is the url that displays the error message. [link](https://contoh.wajaraja.com/pengiklan/Yd21De093)

Comment: Hi @bitski , I need to say, actually i used the attribute with "pengiklan" label name, and not the color (pengiklan has been translated into ID on front end).  When a visitor clicks on the attribute value/link (pengiklan/ID) on the information tab (specifications), the url will became mysite.com/pengiklan/Yd21xxx and at this address I want to display the content before the main content

Comment: @carlozsan ok, then 1st off please swap `color` with `pengiklan` in my code snippet

Comment: I've replaced it but still error.  I also (tried) to add pa_ in pengiklan but the result is the same

Comment: @carlozsan 1. Where did you put that snippet? In your functions.php? If so, could you perhaps show us your functions.php here? 2. From what URL did you go to the mentioned URL https://contoh.wajaraja.com/pengiklan/Yd21De093/?

Comment: 1. I'm using the code snippet plugin to put the code above.

2. [From here](http://prnt.sc/1xmajpq)

I have disabled the code. So now the display is back to normal and you can try it.

Comment: @carlozsa I have finally found the villain i think. Please declare WooCommerce support for your theme adding the extra code i mentioned at my answer's last edit.

Comment: I am using OceanWP theme.

As you can [see here](http://prnt.sc/1xmq83d).

Point 1 > I see there has been similar support.

Point 2 > I tried to add code but can't save it

3. I tried to remove second code (on file function.php) add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_add_woocommerce_support' ); and  successfully save.

4. But when the first code is activated , site shown error again.

Is there anything I missed?

Note : I have removed the extra second code in function.php

Comment: Hi @bitski  I've updated a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69763596/how-i-do-show-something-by-category-to-show-something-by-attribute). Can you see it?
Thank you

Comment: @carlozsa Hello, now with more informations given, i have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: hi @bitski..yes, you are right...and now it display like what i want.  Thank you for taking the time to help me