# How i do : "Show something by category" to "Show something by attribute"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, categories

I have successfully displayed the content before main content by category.

The code is

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content','show_content', 5 );
  function show_content() {
    if( is_product_category( array('sold' ) ) ) {
       echo '<h1>Hello World</h1>';
         }
   }
```

My question, how to change the code to display content based on color attribute?

Any help is greatly appreciated

---

I've tried replacing :

```
if( is_product_category( array('sold' ) ) ) {
```

becomes

```
if ( $product->has_attributes() 'pa_color') {
```

or

```
if ( $product->has_attributes(array('pa_color') {
```

or

```
if ($product->get_attribute('pa_color')){
```

however it didn't work.

Thank you

Comment: Depending on where you want to show something you need the proper hook for that. https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-archiveshopcat-page/ https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/ Also is_product_category() is checking if you are on specific category or category at all. You need to define $product before using it.

Comment: hi @Martin Mirchev...thanks for your reply.  The above code has successfully displayed the content in the location I wanted it to be.  However the content is displayed by category.  I want the content to be displayed based on the color attribute.  Can you help me?

Comment: Since its archive page you have to loop products that are there and if any of the products have attribute color you want to show something ? Or if you have attribute color created you want to show content (doesnt matter if your products have the attribute )

Comment: @MartinMirchev When I write on browser url mysite.com/category/sold > it will displaying all product with categories "sold" + "additional content" from the above code before the main content.

What i want, "additional content" displayed when I write the url mysite.com/color/red. This also applies when I click a link on the additional information tab with an example [like this](http://prnt.sc/1xoygjn).

Comment: Check this - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_tax/ Attributes are taxonomies so use is_tax() to check taxonomy pa_color and for term your color like red.

Comment: @MartinMirchev

Thanks for the reference.
I've read it, then tried replacing if( is_product_category( array('sold') to if ( is_tax( array('pa_color') and it worked.

Now content displaying based on color attribute on location I wanted.

Thank you for the time you have taken to help me.